# Why Spock Framework recommends to use SUS, but there is no such abbreviation in any example?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

Spock framework states that we should use SUS abbreviation for testing entity, but never uses it itself.

Here is the morsel from documentation: [Spock Terminology](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_terminology)

Here are Spock official examples from [GitHub](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example)

What is the right one?

For example:

```java
class EmptyStackSpec extends Specification {
  def stack = new Stack()

  def "size"() {
    expect: stack.size() == 0
  }
}
```

OR

```java
class EmptyStackSpec extends Specification {
  def sus = new Stack()

  def "size"() {
    expect: sus.size() == 0
  }
}
```

So, I'm puzzled. Why does it present in docs if nobody uses it?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I don't think the docs say that it 'should' be used, but rather *and is also called the system under specification or SUS*. Even the example in the doc says `def obj = new ClassUnderSpecification()`. Some people like using `sus` or `sut` for unit tests, but it's a matter of style. I actually find doing this considerably more confusing as I later need to map the name `sus` to something else and as I jump between fixtures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to indicate the Class that is being tested, Spock has the [@Subject](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_subject) annotation for that. The paragraph you linked, doesn't mean that you should actually call the field/variable `sus`, rather it gives you the term to talk about it in an abstract way. If you actually write a specification it is often more helpful to use more descriptive names.